# Example of a monoid having at least 2 members for which $xy = 1$ but $yx \not= 1$

Tags: semigroups, monoid

Can a monoid have at least 2 members for which $xy = 1$ but $yx \neq 1$ ?

I tried matrix multiplication but $ AX = I$ then $XA = I $ too.

Comment: Related questions: [In a non-commutative monoid, is the left inverse of an element also the right inverse?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655186/in-a-non-commutative-monoid-is-the-left-inverse-of-an-element-also-the-right-in/655189#655189), [Left Invertible Elements of a monoid](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463018/left-invertible-elements-of-a-monoid/463703#463703).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [bicyclic monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_semigroup), which is the monoid on two generators $a$ and $b$ under the relation $ab = 1$. Then $ba \not=1$. See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463703) for more details.